# babel-loader not transpiling packages in node_modules even after specifying in exclude block to ignore the package (lerna)

Tags: babeljs, webpack-4, babel-loader, lerna

So I am trying out monorepo design with `lerna` for our react applications.
the idea is to create one repo which will have all the react projects as `lerna` packages as well as some common modules/components which are shared across the applications.

now all these common modules/components are es6 modules. which are not transpiled. because there is continuous development going on the common modules as well. and if we build/transpile them I am sure react HMR will not work after that (a wild guess). following is my directory structure

`package.json
lerna.json
|--packages
     |--common
     |--react-app
     |--constants
     |--utilities`

`common` contains common react elements like `table,accordion` etc. which are exported as default es6 modules.

`react-app` imports `common` as `dependency`. `react-app` has webpack build configuration set.

now when i import `common` module into my `react-app` babel `transform` fails with this error

```
Button.component.jsx 7:19
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (7:19)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| const { Search } = Input;
| class TextBoxWithButton extends React.Component {
>   static propTypes = {
|     placeholder: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
|     onAction: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
 @ ./src/App/Modules/Todo/Components/Header/Header.component.jsx 10:0-111 16:25-41
 @ ./src/App/Modules/Todo/Todo.component.jsx
 @ ./src/App/Router/index.jsx
 @ ./src/App/Layout/index.jsx
 @ ./src/App/index.jsx
 @ ./src/App.hot.js
 @ ./src/index.jsx
```

which means `babel-loader` is unable to parse and transpile whats in the `node_nodules` folder which makes sense because all dependencies are expected to be already transpiled. but not always. if you manage local dependencies you cannot keep them build all the time (that's what i think)

now I have found some solutions online that enable 1`bable-loader` not to exclude `node_modules` or ignoring `@mypackage`in exclude regex. but nothing is working in my case.

here is what i have tried so far.

1. remove `exlucde: /node_modules/` from `babel-loader` => not working
2. use `require.resolve('babel-loader')` => not working
3. add `resolve.symlinks= false`.
4. add `resolve.modules='node_modules'` or 
   `path.resove(__dirname,'node_modules')` => not working
5. add packages path to `babel-loader` include `include: [srcPath, lernaPackagesPath]`,

nothing seem to work.
is there something that i am missing ? 
[here](https://github.com/hannadrehman/react-monorepo) is the link to my git test repo.

Comment: Don't have time to answer, but FYI: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/8651#issuecomment-419601535

Comment: @loganfsmyth do share your answer. i have wasted enough time on this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`babel-loader` by default will not transpile anything that is in `node_modules`. you can explicitly say what to transpile in `node_modules` but after `@babel7.0.0` that doesn't seem to work either. 
there is also a scope of `.babelrc` which was introduced in `@babel7.0.0`.

according to the research i did in under normal circumstances `node_modules` expect to have transpiled `commonjs` or `umd` modules. which can be imported by any application. in my case my packages/components where all `es6` modules which needed to be transpiled. and my webpack build was failing because `babel-loader` was simply ignoring them.

so i decided to use `@babel/cli` to transpile each package where my components reside i had to add `.babelrc` along with other configurations to my component packages and build them with `@babel/cli`

here is the `scripts` in my `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "babel src --watch --out-dir dist --source-maps inline --copy-files --ignore spec.js,spec.jsx"
  },
```

and my package.json looks something like this after that

```
{
  "name": "@pkg/components",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "description": "a repository for react common components. may or may not be dependent on elements",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "author": "hannad rehman",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "babel src --watch --out-dir dist --source-maps inline --copy-files --ignore spec.js,spec.jsx"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@pkg/constants": "^1.0.1",
    "@pkg/elements": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1"
  }
}
```

with this approach. all of my common packages will be unit tested, linted and built before any application can import them. `babel` has a watch mode which will make sure transpilation happens always when a change occurs.

lastly and most importantly react `HMR` works as expected.

***UPDATE***

the above solution definitely works but after months i changed it by using include property in the babel loader

```
{
      test: /\.js(x?)$/,
      include: [/node_modules\/@pkg/],
      use: [
        'thread-loader',
        {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            cacheDirectory: true,
            configFile: path.resolve(
              __dirname,
              '../../../../',
              `${env.appConfig.folderSrc}/babel.config.js`,
            ),
          },
        },
      ],
    }
```